# How to find time difference in seconds using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

How can I find time difference in seconds between two different timezones.
I want to use moment for this -
My start time is something like- `2022-09-04T07:29:39Z[UTC]` and end time will be the current time in my frontend.

My code =

```
 var now  = new Date().getTime();
 var then = "2022-03-04T07:29:39Z[UTC]";
 var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")); //NAN
 var d = moment.duration(ms);
 var s = d.format("hh:mm:ss");
 console.log("Time Difference =",s);
```

I need help in this, currently I am getting `ms` as NAN how can I correct it!

Comment: you are using invalid date format "2022-03-04T07:29:39Z[UTC]";

Comment: Do I need to remove [UTC] ? I tried and this worked but I am curious is it correct or not

Answer (score 1):

This type of calculation can easily be done with Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
 const now  = new Date().getTime(),
  then = new Date("2022-03-04T07:29:39Z"),
  tsec= Math.round((now-then)/1000),
  sec=tsec%60, tmin=(tsec-sec)/60,
  min=tmin%60, th=(tmin-min)/60,
  h=th%24, d=(th-h)/24;
 
 console.log(`Time Difference = ${d}d ${h}h ${min}m ${sec}s`);
```

Comment: ok sir thank you, I am new to JS trying to learn the date-time concept. I am bit confused with the format of date I am getting - "2022-03-04T07:29:39Z[UTC]", what is the use of [UTC] should I need to remove it from the date?

Comment: [UTC] is the form readable to humans but there is a date format as specified in ISO 8601 that uses "z" for marking the GMT timezone.

Answer (score 0):

`d.format` is not a function exposed by momentjs instead of that you should write like below

```js
var now  = new Date().getTime();
var then = "2022-03-04T07:29:39Z[UTC]";
var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")); 
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = moment(d).format('hh:mm:ss')
console.log("Time Difference =",s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is giving invalid time !

Comment: @Amara it's working fine, you can check the running snippet attached.

Comment: The snippet shows me a result of exactly 12 hours any time I run it.  On the third line, the value of ms is NaN.  The moment constructors are being supplied a format hint string that doesn't match either seed value.